# Storing only time in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to store only time in flask sqlalchemy.
Because there is only datetime available to us and I want to store only time.

Comment: have you tried or researched this?

Comment: Use timestamp as a column type, for example. And +1 to Chris' question.

Comment: I'm surprised few people voted it down, this is a legit question, see my answer below.

Comment: +Chris Hawkes and Igor T. yes I researched about this and searched on many websites including stackoverflow but couldn't find an appropriate answer that's why I asked here.As pointed out by MOCKBA this is a legit question with a proper answer.I don't know what all the downvotes are about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I assume you want to use MySQL TIME type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html:

```
root@localhost [test]> show create table Foo\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: Foo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [inDB]> insert into Foo(time) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

root@localhost [inDB]> select * from Foo;
+----+----------+
| id | time     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 20:35:36 |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To create it via sqla, you have to include mysql-specific dialect:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import TIME
Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Foo'
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    time = Column(TIME(), nullable=False)
```